# What exactly is SOA in the .NET world? Is it a design strategy only?

Tags: c#, wcf, soa

Is SOA (in the .net world) mostly a design strategy on building a application that brings together various endpoints?

i.e. a web service layer (WCF) allows for different clients to connect and consume services, MSMQ is used to provide reliable messaging and consuming in a transaction manner.

Would love a real world 'human' answer to this with specific technologies used/patters etc.

Comment: SOA has many definitions and WCF is not necessarily used in SOA or vice versa. This question is overly broad.

Comment: SOA is a design strategy, no matter what world you're in.  What kind of details are you fishing for?

Comment: Good luck getting an exact answer to this question!

Answer (score 2):

SOA is a design pattern that aims to create components in your system as loosely-coupled services that collaborate with one another.  It is a natural extension of object-oriented programming (applied at the system level) and is not technology specific.

WCF is a technology that makes *implementing* an SOA easier in .NET by providing a simple abstraction over common messsage transport mechanisms and allow those services to talk to one another.  Note if you are using web services as the underlying mechanism the endpoints don't even need to both be .NET